# Problems with uploading in php

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have a small problem when it shows the image code but it feels right in the browser instead appear in the image, the image appears a drawing, which will be the problem.

```
<?php
$conn = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Problemas na conexão.");
$db = @mysql_select_db("manutencao", $conn) or die ("Problemas na conexão");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
while ($usuario = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
    // Exibimos a foto
    echo "<img src='C:xampp/htdocs/IMAGENS_SALVAS/".$usuario->foto."' alt='Foto de exibição' /><br />";

}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain your problem with more details I don't understand what do you mean "the image appears a drawing"?

Comment: Your `src` should be the the url for the image, not the system path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line:

```
echo "<img src='C:xampp/htdocs/IMAGENS_SALVAS/".$usuario->foto."' alt='Foto de exibição' /><br />";
```

To this:

```
echo "<img src='/IMAGENS_SALVAS/".$usuario->foto."' alt='Foto de exibição' /><br />";
```